# How do I wrap a RichText widget and then, if the richtext widget is too big for the expanded, scale it down?

Tags: flutter

I have two expanded widgets in a column.  The first expanded widget contains a RichText widget that contains variable length text.  If the text overflows it is cut off.  What I want to acheive is the whole RichText widget scaling down if the content is too big.  I have tried FittedBox which usually works well for Text widgets but when I apply this to a RichText widget the widget it scaled down but the wrapping is removed.  How do I wrap and then, if the richtext widget is too big for the expanded then scale down?

```
return Container(
    child: Column(children: [
  Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      // child:FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
      child: RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
            text:
                "I am a TextSpan widget and am veyr very long lskjdf lskdj flksj dflksjd lfkj",
            style:
                DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.copyWith(fontSize: 35)),
      )),
  Expanded(flex: 4, child: Text("blah blah"))
]));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you tried following the logic of this library: https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text?

Answer (score 3):

[**UPDATED**]

Using [AutoSizeText](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) package:

```
Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 1,
        // child:FittedBox(fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
        child: AutoSizeText.rich(
          TextSpan(text: "A really long String"),
          style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.copyWith(fontSize: 35),
        )
      ),
      Expanded(
        flex: 4,
        child: Text("blah blah")
      )
    ]
  )
)
```

Comment: Was already addressed over the comments and linking libraries, without any examples or explanations of how it works, is not an answer.

Comment: I did try this package before I posted actuslly but I couldn't get it to work without setting a maximum number of lines

Comment: many thanks for your efforts but your example doesn't display rich text and also it has a height and a width (I need to be in an expandable widget)

Comment: @orangesherbert I realized `AutoSizeText` also works with `RichText` for which I failed to include in my answer. It also works without setting a maximum number of lines and without necessarily putting it in a `Container` with a height and width

Comment: @orangesherbert check answer for the updates. I hope this works fine for you.

Comment: Many thanks @mjhansen for trying again but still no luck unfortunately; the text is still cut off if the font size is set too large for the container.